# xpath searching for a node depending on its attributes

Tags: search, xpath, attributes, fxml

I'm not sure how to word this question and maybe that is why I couldn't really find a thread on it... BUT..

I'm looking to grab all the fx:ids of TextFields from the FXML.

```
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <TextField fx:id="_azimuth" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
    <TextField fx:id="_elevation" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

</GridPane>
```

I looked around and saw a couple on how to parse the search based on the id's or attributes of the fxml element, but not the other way around...

such as (never tested this code, but its similar to the examples I'm referring to):

```
String expression = "/GridPane/TextField[@fx:id='_elevation']";
```

I'm just looking for the inverse of this... :\

If this has been answered before in another thread, could you please direct me there? Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Put Labels instead of TextFields. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer through my mentor, but here is the snippet of code AFTER I have read my FXML into a NodeList.

```
Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
NodeList temp = node.getChildNodes();
for(int i = 0; i < temp.getLength(); i++){
    System.out.println(i + ": " + temp.item(i).getNodeName());
    if(temp.item(i).getNodeName().equals("TextField")){
        System.out.println(temp.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("fx:id").getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1: TextField
_elevation
2: #text
```